# ImportError in Metasearch plugin

Tags: qgis

I'm not a programmer and a fairly outdated mac-user. However, got a new mac again and tried to install QGIS on High Sierra. It opens, but there is an error message about Metasearch:

> 2018-01-16T16:59:18   1   Traceback (most recent call last):
>               File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py",
>   line 333, in startPlugin
>                 plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
>               File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/MetaSearch/**init**.py",
>   line 29, in classFactory
>                 from MetaSearch.plugin import MetaSearchPlugin
>               File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py",
>   line 607, in _import
>                 mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>               File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/MetaSearch/plugin.py",
>   line 33, in 
>                 from MetaSearch.dialogs.maindialog import MetaSearchDialog
>               File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py",
>   line 607, in _import
>                 mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>               File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/MetaSearch/dialogs/maindialog.py",
>   line 43, in 
>                 from owslib.csw import CatalogueServiceWeb
>               File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py",
>   line 607, in _import
>                 mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>               File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/owslib/csw.py",
>   line 27, in 
>                 from owslib.util import OrderedDict
>               File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py",
>   line 607, in _import
>                 mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>               File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/owslib/util.py",
>   line 35, in 
>                 import requests
>               File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py",
>   line 607, in _import
>                 mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)           ImportError: No module named requests

How (and where) can I fix that problem?